# Как сделать, чтобы форма не работала, пока работает дочерняя

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

У меня в программе есть главная форма и несколько дочерних. Как сделать так, чтобы пока работает другая форма, главная "заснула"?

Comment: Что конкретно означает «заснула»? Не реагировала на действия пользователя? Откройте второе окно как модальное.

Comment: @VladD Заснула, конкретно это - одела пижамку и легла в кроватку. ТС, пожалуйста не используйте в вопросе выражения и формулировки, которые могут быть поняты двояко.

Comment: @0xdb: Раз так, я бы посоветовал спеть ей колыбельную. А если серьёзно, ТС, думаю, путает саму форму как UI-элемент и модельные процессы, запущенные этой самой формой. Отсюда и мой вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вызывайте дочернюю форму не через `form.Show();`, а через `form.ShowDialog();`.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо подключить библиотеку `System.Windows.Threading`, затем для каждой формы создать отдельный поток

```
Thread th1=new Thread(); 
Thread th2=new Thread();
```

с помощью методов

```
.Sleep()
.Start()
```

включать/отключать потоки

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` значит вовсе не то, что вы предполагаете. Эта функция не позволяет «усыпить» _чужой_ поток.